# Android Compound View, NullPointerExceptionError

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I am trying to build a compound view, it gives me the following error:

> 06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.uitest/com.example.uitest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   06-10 10:32:31.958: E/AndroidRuntime(5748): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

and following is my code in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MyCompoundView catView = new MyCompoundView(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(catView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

But when I using the following code in OnCreate method, it works well

> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
> setContentView(new MyCompoundView(this));

I don't understand why the first method causes the NullPointer error, could anyone kindly give me an explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are passing the scope through `this` before the scope is initialized and hence the result whereas in the second case you are passing the scope (`this`) after initializing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you are passing your current activity to MyCompoundView before the call to onCreate() method is done. Since onCreate() is the method called when the activity is first created, then this will result in a null pointer exception.